# django-oscar-api conflict with Django's UpdateCacheMiddleware: {TypeError}cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object

Tags: django, django-oscar

I implemented django's [per site cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache) in a django-oscar project with django-oscar-api. I use LocMemCache as a cache backend.

Before adding `django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware` to my middlewares, everything worked fine and I could make a request to the "basket" endpoint like this and it returned a 200 response:

```py
import requests

session = session.Session()
r_basket = session.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/basket/")
```

After adding the per-site caching the response has the status code 500. I debugged it and it fails in the `UpdateCacheMiddleware` with the following error: `{TypeError}cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object`.

Other endpoints seem to work fine, but I haven't tested them all yet.
The error can also be reproduced on a freshly installed [django-oscar sandbox](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/internals/sandbox.html#run-the-sandbox-locally). I pip-installed the django-oscar-api and added it to the installed apps, and the MIDDLEWARE setting looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',

    # Allow languages to be selected
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    # per site caching
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',

    # Ensure a valid basket is added to the request instance for every request
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
]
```

My package versions are Django v.3.2.9, django-oscar v.2.2 or 3.0, django-oscar-api v.2.1.1.

What object can not be pickled? Or is the order of the middlewares possibly wrong?

#### Traceback:

```
[2021-11-13 08:43:33,256] Internal Server Error: /api/basket/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/cache.py", line 111, in process_response
    response.add_post_render_callback(
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in add_post_render_callback
    callback(self)
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/cache.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    lambda r: self.cache.set(cache_key, r, timeout)
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/cache.py", line 39, in wrapped
    value = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/cache.py", line 94, in set
    return self.cache.set(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/virtual_environments/django-oscar-sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/locmem.py", line 56, in set
    pickled = pickle.dumps(value, self.pickle_protocol)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

#### expected response

```
{'id': 1,
 'owner': None,
 'status': 'Open',
 'lines': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/baskets/1/lines/',
 'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/baskets/1/',
 'total_excl_tax': '0.00',
 'total_excl_tax_excl_discounts': '0.00',
 'total_incl_tax': '0.00',
 'total_incl_tax_excl_discounts': '0.00',
 'total_tax': '0.00',
 'currency': None,
 'voucher_discounts': [],
 'offer_discounts': [],
 'is_tax_known': True}
```

View: `oscarapi.views.basket.BasketView`

Comment: Can you add the full traceback from the error? Which view causes the issue and can you add it's contents too?

Comment: @IainShelvington I updated the question with the requested infos

Comment: According to the docs you need to ensure the UpdateCacheMiddleware is before SessionMiddleware and LocaleMiddleware https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#order-of-middleware

Comment: @IainShelvington wow, great! thank you! This is correct. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that UpdateCacheMiddleware is before SessionMiddleware and LocaleMiddleware in your settings. [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#order-of-middleware)

FetchFromCacheMiddleware needs to be after those middleware, can be left where it is

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    # Moved UpdateCacheMiddleware to here
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',

    # Allow languages to be selected
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    # per site caching
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',

    # Ensure a valid basket is added to the request instance for every request
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
]
```